How do I access the files I uploaded to a web hosting site?
Sorry I’m sure this a super basic question but I’m using site ground as a web host and I can’t seem to access any of my files when I try to type in their URL in a browser (except for the index.html file which does correctly bring me to the top level domain name). How do I access them?

I tried typing in every kind of URL possible including the names of the sub folders to access it but I can’t get it to work. I’m using site ground

Maybe start from here? https://login.siteground.com/login

As part of your onboarding pack (the documents you get when you become a customer of theirs) you should have been given details for FTP/FTPS or SSH/SFTP access. Check your inbox, perhaps?
